# Where are RTC plugins installed in RAD or where are they located?

Tags: plugins, rtc, ibm-rad

I want to know the path where RTC plugins are installed in RAD. So I can copy the plugins and share with others.

Can anybody please share that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like any other Eclipse plugin, as described in "[Installing the Rational Team Concert client in Eclipse by using the p2 installation repository](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jazz.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_client_installation_p2.html)"

The plugin should be in folders `plugins` and `features` within your RAD installation path.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through this link. But I don't know why I am not getting it under plugins. I see only org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400 plugin

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I got the path. It is under p2 > cic.p2.cache.location > plugins within RAD installation path

Comment: Right, my first link mentioned p2 indeed.